# getting exceptions with jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am attempting to set up my jqGrid to get data from a function on document.ready.  Somehow I am running into several small exceptions when I do this... I thought originally that maybe my json data was malformated...

```
{"total": 2,
"page": 1,
"records": 15,
"rows": [{
    "id": 2148,
    "cell": {
        "MRN": "840134833",
        "Hospital_Fin": "987141516",
        "First_Name": "YELLOW",
        "Last_Name": "CRAYON",
        "Date_of_birth": "\/Date(1253160000000)\/"          
    }
},
{
    "id": 1898,
    "cell": {
        "MRN": "785528039",
        "Hospital_Fin": "6669511596226",
        "First_Name": "RAYFIELD",
        "Last_Name": "BOYD",
        "Date_of_birth": "\/Date(-720298800000)\/"
    }
}]}
```

But it appears to look right.

I get this exception, for instance:

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'integer': object is null or undefined
```

I get that exception at the following line in the code...

```
fmt = $.jgrid.formatter.integer || {};
```

I set up my grid as follows

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#frTable").jqGrid ({
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            caption: '@TempData["POPNAME"]' + ' Population',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAjaxPagedGridData", "Encounters", new { popId = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })',//'/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/'+ '',                
            pager: '#pager',
            loadonce: true,
            height: 450,
            gridview: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 15,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            colNames: [...],
            colModel: [
                   { name: 'MRN', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Hospital_Fin', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Date_of_birth', width: 145, align: 'left' },]
```

Where colNames and colModel are unimportant.
Im at my wits end here.  This should be working.  What am I missing?

Comment: The colModel may not be so irrelevant, are you setting any formatters in there?

Comment: actually I am I will update my post...

Comment: Are you including at least one of the locale files?

Comment: not in the script no.

Comment: There may be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing the required locale file, where the $.jqgrid.formatter is defined:

[jqGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ahow_to_install)

You need to include jQuery, the jqGrid plugin and one of the jqGrid locale files for it to work, for example:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jqID

Comment: That was it.  You also must make sure the local file is imported BEFORE jqGrid.  Or you will be thrown a whole bevy of exceptions.  Unfortunately, my data is still not showing.  But one battle at a time.

Answer (score 0):

That error sounds to me like you have a problem with an object in your view not having been set.  Try setting a static value rather then something like  `TempData["POPULATIONID"]` and I would think you might move forward.

Comment: It is being set.  When I debug and hit that method I see the value.